# image blob detection algorithms

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

> *Note*
>   This is not an exact code question its about algorithm writing and
>   before people close it down, stack overflow is also about algorithms,
>   coding them (and their problems) only comes next. And finding faster or
>   optimal code, happens later.. this Q is really about the earliest
>   phase of writing code.

I try to understand how image "blob" detection works. 
I am looking for some code explanations, preferable in c#. 
There are several methods I read about. The most simple one might be a binary kinda filter working on black and white images.
As explained here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

However that doesn't solve it for me. 
My images are not black and white, they contain more variations (which i cannt split in 2). And I need to apply some rules at blob detection level that some colours belong to the same group only if they match some logic (based upon color info in that blob), despite being visual complete distinct.

I've looked at Aforge (and tested it) EmguCV, OpenCV, and I've seen examples of Matlab (but I don't have Matlab). However since my image data isn't that good for those filters, as I would later like to add even more extra visual logic / future detecting / color rules etc.

So then I red about people sometimes write their own blob filters and this is what I am now interested in. However besides the Wikipedia article I couldnt find some readable programmers material about this subject. I did find things for mathlab, and some heavy mathematical articles about blob / future detecting. What i am looking for are some "other" methods like the Wikipedia article showing some different approaches to blob detection, explained in code. So that i based on such knowledge can create one too.

If someone could point me to some article(s) where people describe  different filter method(s), and isnt about existing aforge/opencv etc. Then i gladly like to learn it.

Comment: Search engines help point people to "some article(s)... which described different filter method(s)". You essentially are trying to write functions based on heavy mathematical algorithms, but are moaning because you don't understand the maths. Do you see the problem there? Use a library and if you must really know the code, analyse it yourself.

Comment: I can point you to sites with heavy math, and i can point  you to the wiki article i mentioned. describing that same article in math would also result in a complex article too. I know other sites exist, as i lost some of my bookmarks. I also allready used the other libraries. And I do want to code it myself.. Not moaning I just need more info in a bit more readable form. preferable finding back the sites i lost.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to think different about the wiki example.
Its using a very flat color system, but if you have more colors you could write a function to check pixels compared to their neighbors, (or special color logic as you mention) maybe an area average, or image average and then use that to fill another image inside a function and return a list of futures or array..or text file whatever. Maybe pre process the image and do some statistics in color distribution. So if your looking for something that is well represented you could find that color, or find color that are less represented.

Unless your after future detection it is one of the most simple and pretty fast algorithm, you could combine it with bitlock and scan images real fast. but be sure not to use paralelism pixel editing since the wiki article would require to compare allready scanned lines. Just a tip